# Filter FileList using TS

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I would like to remove the respective image from the array after clicking on a button. If I declare the whole thing as follows, I get the below message or error from TypeScript

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<FileList | null>(null);

const deleteImage = (image: File) => {
const filteredList: FileList = Array.from(fileList!!).filter(function (img) {
  return img !== image;
});

setFileList(filteredList);

};
```

> Property 'item' is missing in type 'File[]' but required in type 'FileList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Mozilla reference page for `FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) notes that this interface has essentially been deprecated, and recommends that you just use an array of `File` objects instead.

That's what you're doing anyway, ignoring the type declarations – `Array#filter` returns an array, not a file list. So, you could just change `FileList` to `File[]` throughout.

If you really need to preserve compatibility with `FileList` (for an external API perhaps?) then you'll need to wrap that array in something that implements the `.item(..)` accessor. It does not appear that a `FileList` constructor is available in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as FileList` to assert the type of variable:

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<FileList | null>(null);

const deleteImage = (image: File) => {
const filteredList: FileList = Array.from(fileList!!).filter(function (img) {
  return img !== image;
}) as FileList;

setFileList(filteredList);

};
```

Comment: Typescript is (correctly) reporting that the type returned by `filter` does not satisfy the `FileList` interface, because arrays do not have an `item()` method. Maybe consider whether it's appropriate to lie to typescript here (!), and what would happen if a call was made to that method when it isn't actually there ....